# Finding the median of an unsorted array without sorting

Tags: c++, arrays, median

As shown in the title, given an unsorted array (arr) and it's size (size) I'm asked to find the median of it without sorting.

**My thought:**

If the length of the array is odd then It would be easy to find the median by iterating over every element and filter the other elements in the array to numbers less or greater than the candidate to be a median.

**Problems I encountered:**

If the length of the array is even, I thought about using a while loop that divides the size by 2 until size becomes an odd number and then use the code I wrote for odd arrays. The problem is I couldn't slice the array onto sub-arrays of the "new odd size".

**Note:**
It's an intro to C++ course and we don't take complexity in mind as for now.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

float median(int arr[] , int size) {
  float median1;
  if(size % 2 != 0) {
    for(int i=0; i < size; i++) {
      int less_than=0, greater_than=0;
      for(int j=0; j < size; j++) {
        if(arr[i] < arr[j]) {
          greater_than += 1;
        } else if(arr[i] > arr[j]) {
          less_than += 1;
        }
      }
      if (greater_than == smaller_than) {
        median1 = (float)arr[i]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I have to complete the code with for even-sized arrays. I'd like some direction for how can I slice the array (if possible) and I'm open to hear your ways on how can I solve this even without slicing.

Comment: This indentation style is extremely unconventional and makes your code unnecessarily difficult to read.

Comment: Do you have to account for a median which sits between two values on an array with even length? Is that where the other `else` condition (not shown?) kicks in?

Comment: I do not see why you would want to get the median in an array you keep unsorted when it is **both simpler AND faster** to sort it and look at the middle element; this is not a matter of being an experienced developer or not. The 1 thing you can do as a beginner in C++ is avoid C-style arrays in your code for at least the next 10 years and use `std::vector` instead (or `std::array` if the size can be determined at compile time).

Comment: I assume you mean not sorting the array *completely* because computing the median will _by definition_ have the side effect of determining the element that should be sorted into the middle position of the array.  If you are okay with repeatedly just **partitioning** the array and then locating a new pivot on the side of the partition that contains the middle element recursively until the pivot reaches the middle position, then that will work...provided that qualifies as not sorting.  But you do have to rearrange elements to accomplish that.

Comment: It might be solved by [`std::nth_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element)...